# How to make a class automatically prompt itself when setting a value

Tags: c#, winforms

I guess the best way to explain this is with an example:

When setting to `DockStyle` of a `Control`, VS automatically prompts `DockStyle`, 
so basically my class has a private constructor and predefined 'styles' as static instances of itself and I want that class to act like `DockStyle`, other examples that come to mind are `AutoSizeMode`or `Cursors`.

Here's the class in question;

```
public class FormDesign
{
    public static FormDesign Dark = new FormDesign(0)
    {
        // Set Values
    };

    public static FormDesign Grey = new FormDesign(1)
    {
        // Set Values
    };

    public static FormDesign Light = new FormDesign(2)
    {
        // Set Values
    };

    private FormDesign(int i) { ID = i; }

    public FormDesign Switch()
    {
        if(this == Dark) return Grey;
        if (this == Grey) return Light;
        if (this == Light) return Dark;
        return Grey;
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public Color BackColor { get; private set; }
    public Color TitleColor { get; private set; }
    public Color TitleForeColor { get; private set; }
    public Color ForeColor { get; private set; }
    public Color LightColor { get; private set; }
    public Color DarkColor { get; private set; }
    public Color MenuColor { get; private set; }
    public Color LabelColor { get; private set; }
    public Color InfoColor { get; private set; }
    public Color ActiveColor { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I suppose what you want to do is overriding [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx).method of your class. But if you allready *have* an example in mind, why not provide your code shwoing what you *actually* want?

Comment: Have you tried setting the property as an enum then using default value - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultpropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @John No I haven't, I'm not sure how either.

Comment: I think an enum is what you need. As you can see DockStyle is a property that has a type that is an Enum https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle(v=vs.110).aspx 

Can you add an example how you expect people to consume this.

Comment: @John Think that's it, I was looking at the problem from the wrong perspective I guess, Thanks!

Comment: Great, I have added it as an aswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order proper a property to give the implementor a list  of options use an enum.

```
Public Enum Theme
{
  Dark,
  Gray,
  Light
}  

Public Theme ActiveTheme { get; set; }
```

The default value will be the first item in the Enum.

There is the option of using enum classes however this is more complicated. See https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/ for details